# openSUSE shim certificate for uefi secure boot

Tags: security, boot, opensuse

Is openSUSE shim bootloader signed with openSUSE private key?
If so, where can I find the corresponding openSUSE certificate for secure boot verification purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A public key can be retrieved from the shim source package:

1. Download
   http://download.opensuse.org/source/distribution/13.1/repo/oss/suse/src/shim-0.2-3.1.src.rpm
2. Extract using e.g.:
   rpm2cpio shim-0.2-3.1.src.rpm | cpio -dium
3. Unpack tar-ball that is inside:
   tar-xJf shim-12.3-update.tar.xz
4. The certificate can now be found in the usr/lib64/efi subdir:
   openssl x509 -inform der -in usr/lib64/efi/shim-opensuse.der -text

   Certificate:
   Data:
       Version: 3 (0x2)
       Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
   Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
       Issuer: CN=openSUSE Secure Boot CA, C=DE, L=Nuremberg, O=openSUSE Project/emailAddress=build@opensuse.org

You can verify 2nd stage bootloaders and kernels using sbverify from the sbsigntool package (that's what its called on Ubuntu)